# Getting values between widgets in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this widget which it is intended to make some filtering to a Grid View.

```
              content: FilterGridList(
                valueSelectedStart:  varSelectedFilterAgeStart ,
                valueSelectedEnd: varSelectedFilterAgeEnd,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  varSelectedFilterAge = value;
                },
              ),
```

This widget is defined as follow:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: SizedBox(
            child: Card(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('Age'),
              RangeSlider(
                values: _rangeValues,
                divisions: _rangeValues.end.toInt(),
                labels: RangeLabels(_rangeValues.start.round().toString(),
                    _rangeValues.end.round().toString()),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _rangeValues = value;
                    widget.valueSelectedStart = value.start.round().toInt();
                    widget.valueSelectedEnd = value.end.round().toInt();
                  });
                  widget.onChanged(widget.valueSelectedStart);
                  widget.onChanged(widget.valueSelectedEnd);
                },
                min: 0.0,
                max: 20.0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )));
```

I just need to understand how can I retrieve the values selected from RangeSlider in FilterGridList.
These values are related with ages of users and I need to store them in a variable in order to filter my list.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to State Management!  I suggest RiverPod.

Comment: flutter use  inheritedWidget to getting values between widgets
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html